# Trouble with navigation alignment

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to get the navigation on a site aligned properly. What I'm trying to do is have the navigation start at the left side of the page and stop at about 100px from the right side of the main content container div. The navigation is going to be in it's own container with no parent containers (unless someone has a solution that requires otherwise). At the end of the navigation I am going to put an image. The end result will look something like this:

[image]

My main problem is figure out how to set the widths and still be flexible for different screen resolutions. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to put an image at the end and you want responsiveness, then you may want to consider to wrapper it in parent container.

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="leftside">
          <div class="topmenu"></div>
         <div class="botmenu"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="right-side">
          <img src="image.png" />
     </div>
</div>
```

See if this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ut5db/1/) helps

Comment: There is no bottom menu though. The black part is where the page content would go (the usual 1000px width, margin: auto kind of container) which would be centered on the page. The navigation needs to stop 100px from the right side of the black container, but stretch all the way to the left side of the screen

Comment: My answer still applies. remove the botmenu div and stack it under the code I gave you. I'll edit it in the fiddle

Comment: This is just making a navigation that is 75% width and floated left, which doesn't always align properly with the fixed-width page content container that would be underneath it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's just it. In responsive designs when you want to display two objects side by side, you must give it a parent container of 100% and divide the objects within in two sections in which the sum will be 100%. Most headers are 25-75. 25 being the logo, and 75 the nav. You are supposed to float them left so that they align side by side. Otherwise they will stack on top of each other. You can use display:inline, but it's tricky specially if you are going to mess with a nav in there. Refer to Bootstrap.